# INDIRECT for a whole column on another sheet

Tags: excel

Ive searched around for how to use the indirect command for a whole column (on another sheet) but with limited responses

Ive seen it has to be something like this

```
=SUMIF(Site!$A:$A,D11,indirect("Site!$F",Row($F))
```

The reason I want to use indirect is because the cells on that sheet are always changing (and columns are being delted / recreated automatically) - But the data I need will always end up in the same cell (But the formula automatically readjusts when you delete a col etc)

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you just always want to sum column F in your example? You can just use:

```
=SUMIF(Site!$A:$A,D11,INDIRECT("Site!$F:$F")
```

If that's so.

Comment: Strange, I thought I had tried that exactly - But that is working perfectly thanks!!

Comment: @user2761190 You're welcome! You can indicate that you accepted my answer by clicking on the tick outline to the left of my answer :)